# How do I use WPF binding with XML for a specified path with related data from siblings to the parent

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an xml document structured like so:

```
<db>
    <table1>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <val1>1</val1>
            <val2>1</val2>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <val1>2</val1>
            <val2>2</val2>
        </row>
    </table1>
    <table2>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>a</name>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>b</name>
        </row>
    </table2>
    <table3>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>x</name>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>y</name>
        </row>
    </table3>
</db>
```

I need to bind my object to `/db/table1/row[id=1]` and allow child objects to obtain `//db/table{2/3}/row[id={boundrow}/val{1/2}]`

Is it possible to do this directly, or do I have to "create a view" (eg. extract to an object, run an xslt, etc)

Comment: Its hard to understand what you up to. What do you mean with directly? or "create a view"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling you are about to create data structure with bindings.

Bindings transmit a value from target to source but they dont create complete data structure. Therefore first load your tree alike data from xml into clr objects and then bind your TextBoxes to them. Or if you dont want to convert xml into clr objects use XPath property when Binding. Thought you will have to specify where is your xml data located.

Check this link out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx